# Android studio screen starts duplicating

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I have no idea how to actually call the problem that I'm having, because of this i was unable to actually find anything about it.

So i just updated Android studio to version 141,2288178.
Since the update my android studio does weird things, i can use it for about 5 to 10 minutes without any problem. then suddenly my screen starts displaying things on places that it should not be in.[image: Stuff that randomly happens]

Now this is not the craziest it has been.

I have tried multiple things.
1: Restart (worked for 5/10 minutes then its back)
2: restart Computer (Same as before)
3: reinstalled all plugin (did not change anything either)
4: ? reinstall

So i have not reinstalled Android studio yet in the hope that there was a fix that does not require it. My internet here is slow and android studio has a decent file size.

So i am kinda wondering if any of you has a idea on why this is happening and maybe way to fix this. If there isn't a fix beside reinstalling please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you use both of the screens, only one ore none of them?

Comment: Only one. Its a visual glitches, as soon i click somewhere in it or start typing some more code it will start jumping all over the place.